Facial Recognition Converting Face into Cropped Image in Flutter
In accordance with the new docs, Flutter suggested to use NV21 as the image format for captured images.
        imageFormatGroup: Platform.isAndroid
            ? ImageFormatGroup.nv21
            : ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888);

I detect a face for my app, and I'd like to save the image into a database and show the detected face only on a widget. Below, I attempt to translate the face into a croppedFace and display it on a widget. But the image is completely mistranslated.
I've got the face to be detected properly, like in the picture below.

This face is then passed into a function I got from this post to convert it into a imgLib.Image. So the initial inputimage that is fed into convert to NV21 comes from a CameraImage that is converted into an input image using the method in here and the method _inputImageFromCameraImage After this 4 more steps are performed which are
image = imglib.copyRotate(image!,
    angle: camDirec == CameraLensDirection.front ? 270 : 90);

and
imglib.Image croppedFace = imglib.copyCrop(image!,
    x: faceRect.left.toInt(),
    y: faceRect.top.toInt(),
    width: faceRect.width.toInt(),
    height: faceRect.height.toInt());

and then from there I did
         Image.memory(
            Uint8List.fromList(imglib.encodeBmp(croppedFace!)),
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),

in order to show this on my widget.
the face gets detected properly, but the output on the widget looks like this
image.

I really cant solve this problem and have spent days figuring it out. If anyone could have a look through and see what I'm doing wrong, I would highly appreciate it. The code I've used are from the documentation and from Flutter contributors but somewhere along the line, the image is being mis translated. Since the face is being properly detected and set, I assume its to do with conversion from InputImage to imgLib.Image and cropping of the image.
Thank you for any help
